# How to find these eigen vectors?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, gaussian-elimination

Consider the matrix $$B_{\theta}= \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & -\cos{\theta} \end{bmatrix}$$

What are its eigen vectors?

Ofcourse, since this is a rotation matrix, i know that there are only eigen-vectors given that $\theta = n\pi$, whose direction points along the x and y axis.

However how would I actually calculate this?

The characteristic equation is:

$$\lambda^2-1 = 0$$
$$\lambda_{1} = 1 , \lambda_{2} = -1$$

Solving $$[B_{\theta} - 1I]\vec{V} = 0$$

$$\begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta)-1 & \sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & -\cos{\theta}-1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y  \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0  \end{bmatrix}  $$

Writing the extended matrix to use gaussian elimination

$$\left( 
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
        \cos(\theta)-1 & \sin(\theta) & 0 \\
        \sin(\theta) & -\cos{\theta}-1 & 0 \\
    \end{array}
\right)$$

Row operation:

$$R_{1} \rightarrow R_{1} - \frac{\cos(\theta)-1}{\sin(\theta)} R_{2}$$

In order to get this in gaussian form,  i need to divide by $sin(\theta)$ which is zero when theta is $n\pi$, which is the values of which i suspect that there should be solutions.

How do I go about solving for the eigen values? Without using gaussian elimination i cannot find the solutions to the equations. can anyone help?

Comment: Eigenvectors over what field?

Comment: It is not a rotation matrix.  A rotation matrix would be $\pmatrix{\cos x&\sin x\\-\sin x & \cos x}.$  Notice where the negative sign is... So what does this matrix actually do?

Comment: a rotation Plus a reflection

Comment: @DougM: the standard rotation matrix has the negative sign in the $(1,2)$ entry, not the $(2,1)$ entry: it sends $(1,0)$ to $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$, and sends $(0,1)$ to $(\cos(\frac{1}{2}\pi+\theta),\sin(\frac{1}{2}\pi+\theta)) = (-\sin\theta,\cos\theta)$.

Comment: Also note that $\frac {1-\cos \theta}{\sin\theta} = \tan \frac 12 \theta$

Comment: A rotation plus a reflection is a reflection.  One eigenvector is the line of reflection associated with the eigenvalue 1.  The other is the line that is perpendicular to the reflection associated with the eigenvalue -1.

Comment: @DougM we generally put the vector $\begin{pmatrix}\cos x\\\sin x\end{pmatrix}$ in first column in the rotation matrix to have trigonometric orientation, if you put it in row the angle is clockwise orientation.

Comment: What is the line of reflection?  Pick a vector say $\pmatrix{1\\0}$ it gets mapped to $\pmatrix{\cos\theta\\\sin\theta}$  It has been reflected across the line $\frac 12 \theta$....$\pmatrix{\cos\frac 12\theta\\\sin\frac 12\theta}$ is an eigenvector.

Comment: Tan(1/2theta) is identicle to the former by removing a discontinuity, they aren't exactly equal are they?

Comment: I miscalculated my row operations and have the solution. Tan(x/2) is not the same when x =0